# Drag (move) a polygon using Mapstraction

Tags: maps, openlayers, geocoding, polygon, mapstraction

I am struggling to find a way for dragging Polygon using [Mapstraction](http://mapstraction.com/tutorial/events/).
But con't find any example for this.

How do drag polygon in this case?

`JS` Code i have tryed

```
// initialise the map with your choice of API
        var mapstraction = new mxn.MapstractionInteractive('mapstraction','openlayers');
        mapstraction.setCenterAndZoom(new mxn.LatLonPoint(40, -3),5);
        var latlon = new mxn.LatLonPoint(17.384225, 78.486586);
        mapstraction.setCenterAndZoom(latlon, 10);

          var polyPoint;
          var polyPoints = []
          //Adding polygon to map
          polyPoint = new mxn.LatLonPoint(17.447612 , 78.223686)
          polyPoints.push(polyPoint);
          polyPoint = new mxn.LatLonPoint(17.504593 , 78.306084)
          polyPoints.push(polyPoint);
          polyPoint = new mxn.LatLonPoint(17.471193 , 78.417320)
          polyPoints.push(polyPoint);
          polyPoint = new mxn.LatLonPoint(17.414201 , 78.470879)
          polyPoints.push(polyPoint);

          var polygon = new mxn.Polyline(polyPoints);
          polygon.setClosed(true);
          mapstraction.addPolyline(polygon)
```

Comment: I replied to a question very similar to this today:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421144/mapstraction-draw-polygon-dynamically

Is this a duplicate?